# How to remove this door knob on the mortise lockset?

Tags: doors, lock

I have an old mortise lockset that I want to replace. And I already removed all the visible screws and the cylinder. However, I am not able to figure out how to remove the knobs. I could loosen the cover a little bit and I saw a "half" screw head on one of the knob. Posting some pictures here as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you may be able to pull the sleeve covering the "half screw" back to remove said screw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a catch release hidden on the underside of the inner knob. Push in, hold, pull knob out with your 3rd hand.

If you don't care about the knobs you can be lazy and just cut/bend/crush the escutcheon plate to get to the screws.

Comment: May not be underside; may be along the side. Look for a rectangular piece along the knob's shaft. Unlock knobset, push the inner knob's catch inward (I typically use a small screwdriver), pull knob off. Remove rose (the decorative ring) to expose screws.

Comment: Yes it may be a narrow rectangle, but it may be a hole too, that will fit a large straightened paper clip to press inside it to release. It may be difficult to pull, but it will go. Then the escutcheon on that side will slide off to remove the rest

Comment: The release button comes in a wide variety of shapes and sizes. That's why I deliberately didn't try to describe it.